# AD group comparison - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When using the following function (compare 2 user's group membership), I get results that do not make sense.

```
function Compare-ADUserGroups <br>
{  #requires -pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement  
    param (
        [string] $FirstUser = $(Throw "logonname required."),
        [string] $SecondUser = $(Throw "logonname required.")
    )

    $a = (Get-QADUser $FirstUser).MemberOf 
    $b = (Get-QADUser $SecondUser).MemberOf
    $c = Compare-Object -referenceObject $a -differenceObject $b 
    $c | Sort-Object InputObject
}
```

When I call this (Compare-ADUserGroups User1 User2), I get a result set similar to the following:

- CN=[All Users],OU=adm,DC=OSUMC,DC=EDU <=
- CN=[All Users],OU=adm,DC=OSUMC,DC=EDU =>
- CN=Extended Users,OU=MSG,DC=OSUMC,DC=EDU <=
- CN=Extended Users,OU=MSG,DC=OSUMC,DC=EDU =>
- CN=LCS2005,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=OSUMC,DC=EDU <=
- CN=LCS2005,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=OSUMC,DC=EDU =>

I would expect these to not show given that they are equal and I am not using the -IncludeEqual parameter.  Any ideas on why these are showing up?

Answer (score 1):

There's *something* in them which is throwing off the comparison. You'll see something similar if you run...

get-process | export-clixml c\procs.xml
Diff (get-process) (import-clixml c:\procs.xml)

Because SOME properties of those objects - things like VM and PM, for example, change in the brief interval between the two Get-Process runs. So it's possible that you're running into something similar, where some properties between the two objects are differing. By default, Compare-Object looks at *every* property.

An alternative is to use the -property param of Compare-Object to just compare specific properties, rather than comparing the *entire* object. Compare-Object can definitely be a bit tricky in this regard, because of the way it works with object properties rather than simply working with text.

Answer (score 1):

I write an User Interface to compare groups and apply change between 2 users
[image]

```
#requires -version 2
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Compare les groupe entre 2 users
    .DESCRIPTION
        Affiche sur 2 colones les les groupes AD des 2 users a comparer et met en evidance les goupes mamquants de chaque user
    .PARAMETER user1
        Nom complet de l'utilisateur 1 a comparer
        ex : domain.adds\UserName
    .PARAMETER user2
        Nom complet de l'utilisateur 2 a comparer
    .EXAMPLE
        .\Compare-QadUsersGrp.ps1 $(whoami) $($UserNames)
    .EXAMPLE
        Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden powershell -ArgumentList "-WindowStyle Normal .\Compare-QadUsersGrp.ps1 $(whoami) $($UserNames)"
#>


param( 
    [string]$SessionName1 = 'Domain\testalb',
    [string]$SessionName2 = 'Domain\testalb2'
)

$currentRunner = $false
$version = '0.60'
$source = "Script Compare-Sessions (alopez)"
$lanStorage = "c:"

    add-content "$lanStorage\Get-TSAdmin_Usage-Log.txt" -value "[$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')]  $(whoami) - $($version) Compare-Sessions - $SessionName1  vs  $SessionName2"

############################################### Zone liée a l'affichage (refresh) ################################################

    function Refresh-Tabs {
        $loadBar.Visible = $true
        $loadBar.Value = 0

        $ListCompared = Get-vsGrps

        $loadBar.Value = 90
        $SrvForm.height = 178 + $ListCompared.count * 22

        $DefaultColor = 'DarkBlue'
        Set-DataGridView -DataGridView $Grille -AlternativeRowColor -ForeColor $DefaultColor -BackColor 'AliceBlue'

        Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $Grille -Item (ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject ($ListCompared | ?{$_}))
        $Grille.Columns["$SessionName2"].Width=320
        $Grille.Columns["$SessionName2"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = 'MiddleRight'
        #$Grille.Columns["$SessionName2"].AutoSizeMode = $true
        $Grille.Columns["$SessionName2"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = 'MiddleRight'
        $Grille.Columns['#'].Width=20
        $Grille.Columns["$SessionName1"].Width=330
        #$Grille.Columns["$SessionName2"].AutoSizeMode = $true

        $Grille.Columns['DN'].Width = 0
        Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value '==' -FindingColumns '#' -RowForeColor Gray
        Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value '=>' -FindingColumns '#' -RowForeColor Green
        #Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value '<=' -FindingColumns '#' -RowForeColor Blue

        $loadBar.Value = 100
        $loadBar.Visible = $false

    }

    function Set-DataGridView  {
        PARAM (
            [ValidateNotNull()]
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]$DataGridView,

            [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "AlternativeRowColor")]
            [Switch]$AlternativeRowColor,

            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "AlternativeRowColor")]
            [System.Drawing.Color]$ForeColor,

            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "AlternativeRowColor")]
            [System.Drawing.Color]$BackColor,

            [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Proper")]
            [Switch]$ProperFormat
        )
        PROCESS
        {

            $DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = $DefaultColor

            if ($psboundparameters['AlternativeRowColor']) { # les ligne PAIRES
                $DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = $ForeColor
                $DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = $BackColor
            }


            if ($psboundparameters['ProperFormat']) {
                #$Font = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList "Segoi UI", 10
                $Font = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList "Consolas", 10
                #[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold

                $DataGridView.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = 'Raised'
                $DataGridView.BorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
                $DataGridView.SelectionMode = 'FullRowSelect'
                $DataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = $false
                $datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.font = $Font
            }
        }  
    }

    function ConvertTo-DataTable {
        <#
            .SYNOPSIS
                Converts objects into a DataTable.
            .DESCRIPTION
                Converts objects into a DataTable, which are used for DataBinding.
            .PARAMETER  InputObject
                The input to convert into a DataTable.
            .PARAMETER  Table
                The DataTable you wish to load the input into.
            .PARAMETER RetainColumns
                This switch tells the function to keep the DataTable's existing columns.
            .PARAMETER FilterWMIProperties
                This switch removes WMI properties that start with an underline.
            .EXAMPLE
                $DataTable = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject (Get-Process)
        #>
        [OutputType([System.Data.DataTable])]
        param(
            [ValidateNotNull()]
                $InputObject, 
            [ValidateNotNull()]
                [System.Data.DataTable]
                    $Table,
            [switch]    $RetainColumns,
            [switch]    $FilterWMIProperties
        )

        if($Table -eq $null) {
            $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        }

        if($InputObject-is [System.Data.DataTable]) {
            $Table = $InputObject
        } else {
            if(-not $RetainColumns -or $Table.Columns.Count -eq 0) {
                #Clear out the Table Contents
                $Table.Clear()

                if($InputObject -eq $null){ return } #Empty Data

                $object = $null
                #find the first non null value
                foreach($item in $InputObject) {
                    if($item -ne $null) {
                        $object = $item
                        break
                    }
                }

                if($object -eq $null) { return } #All null then empty

                #Get all the properties in order to create the columns
                foreach ($prop in $object.PSObject.Get_Properties()) {
                    if(-not $FilterWMIProperties -or -not $prop.Name.StartsWith('__')) #filter out WMI properties
                    {
                        #Get the type from the Definition string
                        $type = $null

                        if($prop.Value -ne $null) {
                            try{ $type = $prop.Value.GetType() } catch {}
                        }

                        if($type -ne $null) # -and [System.Type]::GetTypeCode($type) -ne 'Object')
                        {
                            [void]$table.Columns.Add($prop.Name, $type) 
                        }
                        else #Type info not found
                        { 
                            [void]$table.Columns.Add($prop.Name)    
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($object -is [System.Data.DataRow]) {
                    foreach($item in $InputObject) {   
                        $Table.Rows.Add($item)
                    }
                    return  @(,$Table)
                }
            } else {
                $Table.Rows.Clear() 
            }

            foreach($item in $InputObject) {       
                $row = $table.NewRow()

                if($item) {
                    foreach ($prop in $item.PSObject.Get_Properties()) {
                        if($table.Columns.Contains($prop.Name)) {
                            $row.Item($prop.Name) = $prop.Value
                        }
                    }
                }
                [void]$table.Rows.Add($row)
            }
        }

        return @(,$Table)   
    }

    function Load-DataGridView {
        <#
            .SYNOPSIS
                This functions helps you load items into a DataGridView.
            .DESCRIPTION
                Use this function to dynamically load items into the DataGridView control.
            .PARAMETER  DataGridView
                The ComboBox control you want to add items to.
            .PARAMETER  Item
                The object or objects you wish to load into the ComboBox's items collection.
            .PARAMETER  DataMember
                Sets the name of the list or table in the data source for which the DataGridView is displaying data.
        #>
        Param (
            [ValidateNotNull()]
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                    [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]
                        $DataGridView,
            [ValidateNotNull()]
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                    $Item,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
                [string]
                    $DataMember
        )
        $DataGridView.SuspendLayout()
        $DataGridView.DataMember = $DataMember

        if ($Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IListSource] -or $Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IBindingList] -or $Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IBindingListView] ) {
            $DataGridView.DataSource = $Item
        } else {
            $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

            if ($Item -is [System.Collections.IList]) {
                $array.AddRange($Item)
            } else {   
                $array.Add($Item)   
            }
            $DataGridView.DataSource = $array
        }
        $DataGridView.ResumeLayout()
    }

    function Find-DataGridViewValue {
        # https://github.com/lazywinadmin/WinFormPS/blob/master/WinFormPS.psm1
        <#
            .SYNOPSIS
                The Find-DataGridViewValue function helps you to find a specific value and select the cell, row or to set a fore and back color.

            .DESCRIPTION
                The Find-DataGridViewValue function helps you to find a specific value and select the cell, row or to set a fore and back color.

            .PARAMETER DataGridView
                Specifies the DataGridView Control to use

            .PARAMETER RowBackColor
                Specifies the back color of the row to use

            .PARAMETER RowForeColor
                Specifies the fore color of the row to use

            .PARAMETER SelectCell
                Specifies to select only the cell when the value is found

            .PARAMETER SelectRow
                Specifies to select the entire row when the value is found

            .PARAMETER FindingColumns
                Specifies the column(s) to search Value or NotValue

            .PARAMETER Value
                Specifies the value to search

            .PARAMETER NotValue
                Specifies the value to not match in all column (param FindingColumns is recomanded)

            .EXAMPLE
                PS C:\> Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value $textbox1.Text

                This will find the value and select the cell(s)

            .EXAMPLE
                PS C:\> Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value $textbox1.Text -RowForeColor 'Red' -RowBackColor 'Black'

                This will find the value and color the fore and back of the row
            .EXAMPLE
                PS C:\> Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value $textbox1.Text -SelectRow

                This will find the value and select the entire row

            .NOTES
                Francois-Xavier Cat
                @lazywinadm
                www.lazywinadmin.com
        #>
        [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Cell")]
        PARAM (
            [ValidateNotNull()]
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]$DataGridView,
            $Value,
            $NotValue,
            [string[]]$FindingColumns,
            #[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Cell")]
            [Switch]$SelectCell,
            #[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Row")]
            [Switch]$SelectRow,
            #[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Column")]
            #[Switch]$SelectColumn,
            [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "RowColor")]
            [system.Drawing.Color]$RowForeColor,
            [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "RowColor")]
            [system.Drawing.Color]$RowBackColor
        )

        PROCESS
        {
            $DataGridView.ClearSelection()
            ForEach ($Col in  $DataGridView.Columns) {
                if ($FindingColumns -contains $Col.Name -or !$FindingColumns) {
                    ForEach ($Row in $DataGridView.Rows) {
                        $CurrentCell = $dataGridView.Rows[$Row.index].Cells[$Col.index]

                        if ((-not $CurrentCell.Value.Equals([DBNull]::Value)) -and ( ($Value -and ($CurrentCell.Value.ToString() -like "$Value")) -or ($NotValue -and ($CurrentCell.Value.ToString() -notlike "$NotValue")) ))
                        {
                            # Append-RichtextboxStatus -ComputerName $textboxSocieteName.Text -Source "Find $Value$NotValue" -Message "Colonne:$($col.name) ligne:$($row.index)"
                            # Row Selection
                            IF ($PSBoundParameters['SelectRow'])
                            {
                                $dataGridView.Rows[$Row.index].Selected = $true
                            }

                            # Row Fore Color
                            IF ($PSBoundParameters['RowForeColor'])
                            {
                                $dataGridView.Rows[$Row.index].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = $RowForeColor
                            }

                            # Row Back Color
                            IF ($PSBoundParameters['RowBackColor'])
                            {
                                $dataGridView.Rows[$Row.index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = $RowBackColor
                            }
                            # Cell Selection
                            ELSEIF (-not ($PSBoundParameters['SelectRow']) -and -not ($PSBoundParameters['RowForeColor']) -and -not ($PSBoundParameters['SelectColumn']))
                            {
                                $CurrentCell.Selected = $true
                            }
                        }#IF not empty and contains value
                    }
                }
            }
        }#PROCESS
    }
############################################### Zone liée aux actions sur les objects ############################################

    $CommonObject = [hashtable]::Synchronized( @{
    })

    function Get-vsGrps {
        Add-PSSnapin 'Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement'

        $loadBar.Value = 10
        $User1 = Get-QADUser -identity $SessionName1
        $loadBar.Value = 20
        $User2 = Get-QADUser -identity $SessionName2
        $loadBar.Value = 30
        $ListCompared = Compare-Object $User1.memberof $User2.memberof -IncludeEqual | %{
            #$_.InputObject=(Get-QADGroup $_.InputObject).Name
            #$_.InputObject = ($_.InputObject -split(','))[0] -replace('CN=','')
            [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                "$SessionName2" = $(
                    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '==' -or $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
                        ($_.InputObject -split(','))[0] -replace('CN=','')
                    } else {
                        ''
                    }
                )
                '#' = $_.SideIndicator
                "$SessionName1" = $(
                    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '==' -or $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=') {
                        ($_.InputObject -split(','))[0] -replace('CN=','')
                    } else {
                        ''
                    }
                )
                DN = $_.InputObject
            }
        } | Sort-Object DN
        $loadBar.Value = 40
        $ListCompared
    }

    function Toggle-Group {
        $loadBar.Value = 0
        $loadBar.Visible = $true
        $loadBar.Value = 50

        $line = $Grille.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        $col = $Grille.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        $DN = $Grille.currentrow.Cells[3].value
        $Grp = ($DN -split(','))[0] -replace('CN=','')

        if (@(0,2) -contains $col -and $edit.Checked) {
            $user = $Grille.columns[$Col].HeaderText
            if ($Grille.CurrentCell.value -eq '' -or $Grille.CurrentCell.value -like " Supp ($Grp) ! ") {
                add-QADGroupMember -identity $DN -member $user
                retour-email -title "$user : Add '$Grp'" -msg "Add $DN"
                $Grille.CurrentCell.value =  " Add ($Grp) ! "
                $Grille.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = 'Magenta'
            }
            else {
                Remove-QADGroupMember -identity $DN -member $user
                retour-email -title "$user : Supp '$Grp'" -msg "Supp $DN"
                $Grille.CurrentCell.value = " Supp ($Grp) ! "
                $Grille.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = 'Red'
            }
            $Grille.currentrow.Cells[1].value = "><"
            $Grille.currentrow.Cells[1].style.ForeColor = 'Red'
        }

        $loadBar.Value = 100
        $loadBar.Visible = $false
    }

    function retour-email {
        param (
            [string] $email = $script:currentRunner,
            [switch] $force = $edit.Checked,
            [string] $title = '.',
            [string] $msg = '.'
        )
        if ( $email -and $force) {
            Send-MailMessage -To $email -from 'Script@mydomain.com' -Subject "$title" -SmtpServer mySmtpServer -BodyAsHtml -Body "$msg"
        }
        add-content "$lanStorage\Get-TSAdmin_Usage-Log.txt" -value "[$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')]  $(whoami) - $($version) Compare-Sessions - $title"
    }


############################################### Zone GUI / Interface - formulaire ###############################################

#requires -version 2

Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Drawing'
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# permet de faire les requette serveur apres ouverture du formulaire
    $timerOnload = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer 
    $timerOnload.Interval = 500
    $timerOnload.add_Tick({
            Refresh-Tabs

            $script:currentRunner = (whoami | Get-QADUser).email

            $edit.Text = "Edit Mode, with email return ($($script:currentRunner))"
            $timerOnload.Enabled = $false
        })
    $timerOnload.Enabled = $true
    $timerOnload.Start()
# 

#region $SrvForm
$SrvForm = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$SrvForm.Name = 'SrvForm'
$SrvForm.MaximumSize = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Drawing.Size' -ArgumentList @(0, 1200)
$SrvForm.MinimumSize = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Drawing.Size' -ArgumentList @(670, 180)
$SrvForm.Size = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Drawing.Size' -ArgumentList @(670, 350)
$SrvForm.Padding = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Padding' -ArgumentList @(1,1,1,0)
$SrvForm.KeyPreview = $True
$SrvForm.Add_KeyDown({ if ($_.KeyCode -eq 'Escape') {$SrvForm.Close()} })
$SrvForm.Add_KeyDown({ if ($_.KeyCode -eq 'F5') {
            Refresh-Tabs
        }
    })
$icon1 = & {
    $iconString = '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'
    $iconStream = New-Object -TypeName 'System.IO.MemoryStream' -ArgumentList @(,([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($iconString)))
    $icon = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Drawing.Icon' -ArgumentList $iconStream
    $iconStream.Dispose()
    return $icon
}
$SrvForm.text = "$SessionName2 vs $SessionName1"
$SrvForm.Icon = $icon1
$SrvForm.Topmost = $True
$SrvForm.Topmost = $false

$SrvForm.SuspendLayout()

    #region $groupBox1
    $groupBox1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox'
    $groupBox1.Text = 'Comparatif des groupes (direct)'
    $groupBox1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
    $groupBox1.SuspendLayout()

        #region $Grille
        $Grille = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
        $Grille.Name = 'Grille'
        $Grille.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
        $Grille.ReadOnly = $true
        $Grille.SelectionMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode]::FullRowSelect
        $Grille.RowHeadersVisible = $false
        $Grille.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
        $Grille.AllowUserToResizeRows = $false
        $Grille.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $false
        $Grille.PerformLayout()

        #endregion $Grille

        [System.Void]$groupBox1.Controls.Add($Grille)

        #region $aide
        $aide = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
        $aide.Name = 'aide'
        $aide.Text = 'Double-click sur un groupe ajoute ou supprime le groupe pour cet utilisateurs'
        $aide.Visible = $false
        $aide.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red
        $aide.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Bottom
        $aide.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleRight
        #endregion $aide

        [System.Void]$groupBox1.Controls.Add($aide)

    $groupBox1.ResumeLayout($false)
    $groupBox1.PerformLayout()
    #endregion $groupBox1

    [System.Void]$SrvForm.Controls.Add($groupBox1)

    #region $panel1
    $panel1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel'
    $panel1.Size = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Drawing.Size' -ArgumentList @(0, 30)
    $panel1.Padding = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Padding' -ArgumentList @(4)
    $panel1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Bottom
    $panel1.SuspendLayout()

        #region $edit
        $edit = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
        $edit.Name = 'edit'
        $edit.Text = 'Mode Edition, avec retour par email de chaque modif'
        $edit.Checked = $false
        $edit.Width = 480
        $edit.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Left
        #endregion $edit

        [System.Void]$panel1.Controls.Add($edit)

        #region $button1
        $button1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
        $button1.Text = 'Retour Email complet'
        $button1.Width = 150
        $button1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Right
        #endregion $button1

        [System.Void]$panel1.Controls.Add($button1)

    $panel1.ResumeLayout($false)
    $panel1.PerformLayout()
    #endregion $panel1

    [System.Void]$SrvForm.Controls.Add($panel1)

    #region $statusStrip1
    $statusStrip1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip'
    $statusStrip1.SuspendLayout()

        #region $LabelVersion
        $LabelVersion = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel'
        $LabelVersion.Text = 'V0.00'
        $LabelVersion.Spring = $true
        $LabelVersion.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft
        #endregion $LabelVersion

        [System.Void]$statusStrip1.Items.Add($LabelVersion)

        #region $loadBar
        $loadBar = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar'
        $loadBar.Style = [System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle]::Continuous
        $loadBar.Value = 100
        $loadBar.Visible = $true
        #endregion $loadBar

        [System.Void]$statusStrip1.Items.Add($loadBar)

    $statusStrip1.ResumeLayout($false)
    $statusStrip1.PerformLayout()
    #endregion $statusStrip1

    [System.Void]$SrvForm.Controls.Add($statusStrip1)

############################################### Zone personalisation du formilaire ##############################################

$LabelVersion.Text = "[PID:$pid] $($script:MyInvocation.MyCommand) - V $Version"

$button1.add_click({
        retour-email -title "$SessionName2  vs  $SessionName1" -msg (Get-vsGrps | ConvertTo-Html)
    })

$Grille.add_DoubleClick({
        Toggle-group
    })

$Grille.add_ColumnHeaderMouseClick({
        Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value '==' -FindingColumns '#' -RowForeColor Gray
        Find-DataGridViewValue -DataGridView $Grille -Value '=>' -FindingColumns '#' -RowForeColor Green
    })

$edit.Add_CheckStateChanged({
        $aide.visible = $edit.Checked
    })

$SrvForm.ResumeLayout($false)
$SrvForm.PerformLayout()
#endregion $SrvForm

#region GUI Startup
$SrvForm.ShowDialog()
#endregion GUI Startup

#$powershell.Dispose()
#$runspace.close()
$timerOnload.stop()

Get-vsGrps
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the MemberOf property provided by `Get-QADUser` is probably returning an object instead of just the distinguished name of the group as a string. Here is the script that I use for comparing Active Directory Group memberships:

```
# Compare the group memberships of 2 Active Directory Users or the user memberships of 2 Active Directory Groups.
# Requires the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module from the Microsoft's Remote Server Administration Tools.

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ComparisonResult ($name1, $name2, $sideIndicator)
{
    $comparisonResult = $null

    switch ($_.SideIndicator)
    {
        '<=' { $comparisonResult = "$($name1) Only" }
        '==' { $comparisonResult = "$($name1) and $($name2)" }
        '=>' { $comparisonResult = "$($name2) Only" }
    }

    return $comparisonResult
}

function Compare-ADUserGroupMembership($userName1, $userName2)
{
    $userComparisonResultColumn = @{ name = 'Comparison Result'; expression = { Get-ComparisonResult $user1.DisplayName $user2.DisplayName  $_.SideIndicator } }
    $groupNameColumn = @{ name = 'Group Name'; expression = { (Get-ADGroup $_.InputObject).Name } }

    $user1 = Get-ADUser $userName1 -Properties memberOf, displayName
    $user2 = Get-ADUser $userName2 -Properties memberOf, displayName

    $userGroupComparison = Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $user1.MemberOf $user2.MemberOf | Select $userComparisonResultColumn, $groupNameColumn

    return $userGroupComparison
}

function Compare-ADGroupMembership($groupName1, $groupName2)
{
    $groupComparisonResultColumn = @{ name = 'Comparison Result'; expression = { Get-ComparisonResult $groupName1 $groupName2 $_.SideIndicator } }
    $userNameColumn = @{ name = 'User Name'; expression = { $_.InputObject.name } }

    $groupMembers1 = Get-ADGroupMember $groupName1
    $groupMembers2 = Get-ADGroupMember $groupName2

    $groupMemberComparison = Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $groupMembers1 $groupMembers2 | Select $groupComparisonResultColumn, $userNameColumn

    return  $groupMemberComparison
}

Compare-ADUserGroupMembership 'userone' 'usertwo' | ft -AutoSize
Compare-ADGroupMembership 'Group One' 'Group Two' | ft -AutoSize
```